# The message buffer struct(mbuf): Linux equivalent

Tags: linux, network-programming

Is there an equivalent in Linux for the mbuf(message buffer)data structures that holds the actual packet data that is to be transmitted over networks? I assumed that this is a generic UNIX structure but apparently it's unique to FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `sk_buff`, I don't know enough to say how much alike it is with `mbuf` in practise: [Networking: sk_buff](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/sk_buff).

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the **mbuf**(message buffer) and **pbuf**(packet buffer) structures are part of the FreeBSD network stack. The **sk_buff**(socket buffer) is the Linux equivalent of mbuf and contains all the information about the message data being transmitted as well as the packet structure.